# How to extend arrow? (and similar classes in modules)

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, python-module, arrow-python

I am trying to extend [`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and fail to understand how I can replicate the functionality of the base classes. This is probably due to a lack of clear understanding on how to extend classes in modules (emphasized by my `arrow` case - this is to say that the question is probably more general than limited to `arrow` only).

`arrow` basic usage:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.now()
<Arrow [2016-11-19T15:13:23.897484+01:00]>
>>> arrow.get("2016-11-20")
<Arrow [2016-11-20T00:00:00+00:00]>
```

I would like to add a `when` method which will return 'today', 'tomorrow' or 'later'. I first tried this:

```
import arrow

class MyArrow(arrow.Arrow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        arrow.Arrow.__init__(self, *args)

    def when(self):
        now = arrow.now()
        end_today = now.ceil('day')
        end_tomorrow = now.replace(days=+1).ceil('day')
        start_tomorrow = now.replace(days=+1).floor('day')
        if self < end_today:
            return 'today'
        elif self < end_tomorrow:
            return 'tomorrow'
        else:
            return 'later'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tom = MyArrow.now().replace(days=+1)
    print(tom.when())
    someday = MyArrow.get("2016-11-19")
```

The result is

```
tomorrow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dropbox/dev/domotique/testing/myarrow.py", line 23, in <module>
    someday = MyArrow.get("2016-11-19")
AttributeError: type object 'MyArrow' has no attribute 'get'
```

So the first part worked, but `get()` failed. I had a look at [the sources](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow/tree/master/arrow) and `get` is in `ArrowFactory`. If I extend `ArrowFactory` instead of `Arrow` I will be able to use `get` but not `now()` anymore.

**This is the point I am at loss**: the "basic usage" above shows that I can call `arrow.whatever_is_available` no matter if it is defined in the class `Arrow` or `ArrowFactory`.
How does this work?
How can I add my `when` method to keep the rest of `arrow` as it is (and all its methods)?

Comment: `arrow.get` isn't a method on `Arrow`, it's [a function in `api`](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow/blob/master/arrow/api.py#L17) that exposes the factory's API. You can create a new factory for your own class by calling `ArrowFactory(MyArrow)`, on which you can then call `.get`. This specific problem is related to `arrow`, which is relatively complex internally; in general just subclassing the module's classes is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Extensible for your own Arrow-derived types

is one of the highlighted [features](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#features) in Arrow's documentation, which actually demonstrates [exactly how to create and use a custom `Arrow` subclass](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#factories):

> #### Factories
>
> Use factories to harness Arrow’s module API for a custom Arrow-derived
>   type. First, derive your type:
>
> ```
> >>> class CustomArrow(arrow.Arrow):
> ...
> ...     def days_till_xmas(self):
> ...
> ...         xmas = arrow.Arrow(self.year, 12, 25)
> ...
> ...         if self > xmas:
> ...             xmas = xmas.replace(years=1)
> ...
> ...         return (xmas - self).days
> ```
>
> Then get and use a factory for it:
>
> ```
> >>> factory = arrow.Factory(CustomArrow)
> >>> custom = factory.utcnow()
> >>> custom
> >>> <CustomArrow [2013-05-27T23:35:35.533160+00:00]>
>
> >>> custom.days_till_xmas()
> >>> 211
> ```

You can then call the `.get`, `.now` and `.utcnow` methods on the `factory` and get your custom subclass, with its `.when` method.

This is specific to dealing with Arrow and its module-level API; with simpler modules, you could just subclass their classes directly.

Comment: Thank you. Damn, how is that that I never see these things in the documentation - the example given is almost identical to what I wanted to achieve (and yes, I was quite scared when looking at the sources)